# jquery global variable can not access from outside

Tags: jquery, post

i try to write some jquery delete function, it is delete ok.
My problem is before delete i will checking from database if there are exist id = CategoriIDs int values. If values exist delete not work, else wil be delete.

I set global variable for CategoriIDs but it returns undefined.

```
var CategoriIDs;
       $.post("menulerListe.php", {
        }, function() {

                $('.bunuSil').each(function() {
                var CategoriIDs = $(this).attr("value"); 
                    console.log(CategoriIDs);//listin all catids ok.

           });
        });


    $(document).on("click", ".bunuSil", function() {

        var kayitID = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(CategoriIDs);//returns undefined.

         if(jQuery.inArray(kayitID, CategoriIDs) == -1){
                console.log("it is not there");

             return false;

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it with ajax json method:

```
$(document).on("click", ".bunuSil", function() {
    var kayitID = $(this).attr("id");
    var baslik = $(this).attr("value");

    //var confirmation = confirm(baslik + "Silinsin mi?");

    //if (confirmation) {

        $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            method: "post",
            url: 'menuler_Baslik_modal_sil.php',
            data: {
                kayitSil: kayitID
            },
            success: function(sonuc) {

                if (sonuc.ok) {
                    kayitListe();

                    $("#kayitSilSonuc").html(sonuc.ok);
                } else {
                    confirm(sonuc.hata);

                }

            }


        });

        //alert('removed');
    //}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do is do a ajax call for checking values from DB and then accorsing to reponse do further actions of your delete. Dont store or use any global variables

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you redefine the `var CategoriIDs = $(this).attr("value");` inside the function scope of the `each()` call (you redefine it because you write `var` again). Therefore the variable assignment there applies to the local scope, and the value doesn't get saved in the one you defined before. If you remove the `var` from that statement, it should work, but only after the ajax call has successfully been made an that piece of code has been reached (you can do a `console.log()` where the var is set to check if it is actually being set).

Answer (score 0):

You have declared a new `CategoriIDs` variable 2 functions down so your global isn't being used.

```
var CategoriIDs;
       $.post("menulerListe.php", {
        }, function() {

                $('.bunuSil').each(function() {
                CategoriIDs = $(this).attr("value");  // Removed 'var'
                    console.log(CategoriIDs);//listin all catids ok.

           });
        });


    $(document).on("click", ".bunuSil", function() {

        var kayitID = $(this).attr("id");
        console.log(CategoriIDs);//returns undefined.

         if(jQuery.inArray(kayitID, CategoriIDs) == -1){
                console.log("it is not there");

             return false;

            }
```

Comment: var CategoriIDs;
           $.post("menulerListe.php", {
            }, function() {

                    $('.bunuSil').each(function() {
                    CategoriIDs = $(this).attr("value"); // i can list all catids here..
                        
               });
            });

        $(document).on("click", ".bunuSil", function() {
       
            var kayitID = $(this).attr("id");
            
           console.log(CategoriIDs); //still getting undefined, i need list all cat ids here